# How to dynamically change the display text of a button in xcode using tags

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

Im trying to create an email us button in my app where the text displayed changes depending on what version of the app youre using. Currently the text is "Email: " and i want to add an email address to that text. 
The button is in a table view cell, and i want to change this text using tags, how would i go about this or is there another option?
P.S The reason i want to do it with tags is when i try to hook the button up to an outlook the build will fail

```
        let sendEmailButton = cell.viewWithTag(666)!
        var rect = sendEmailButton.frame
        rect.origin.x = 19
        sendEmailButton.frame = rect
        rect.origin.y = 75
        sendEmailButton.frame = rect
        change text here to be add email address
```

In this code i'm moving the button into its position, and then i want to change its text. Again, there no outlet as that caused fails due to it being in a table view. I realise this screen should not be in a table view, but its the way my company does it and i have to work with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cast your button as UIButton like this:

```
guard let sendEmailButton = cell.viewWithTag(666) as? UIButton else { return }
```

and than just set title

```
sendEmailButton.setTitle("here goes your text", for: .normal)
```

Comment: Hey, that looks like a good solution, but when i put that code in im getting this warning "Non-void function should return a value"

Comment: I have added the entire file to the post

Comment: Just change 'guard let' to 'if let' and get rid of return

Answer (score 0):

For your code it will be work.

```
    if let button = cell.viewWithTag(666) as? UIButton {
        button.setTitle("Set Your Text here", for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: When i try that code, i get a fatal error due to a nil. How would i go about fixing that?

Comment: Can you please tell me the which number of line send you a  fatal error